# Trying to flip a triangle css

Tags: css

Been trying to follow and play with this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bossy_nova/wBUW7/1/

I've been looking for a way to get this kinda triangle to become a downward facing triangle. Played with the rotations, and that didn't prove useful. Am I missing something?

So how do I flip this arrow? Thanks for you help in advance.

```
.triangle-with-shadow {
   width: 100px;
   height: 50px;
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
   box-shadow: 0 0px 0px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.triangle-with-shadow:after {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   background: #999;
   transform: rotate(45deg);
   -ms-transform:rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
   -moz-transform:rotate(45deg); /* Firefox */
   -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
   -o-transform:rotate(45deg); /* Opera */
   top: 25px;
   left: 25px;
   box-shadow: -1px -1px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}​
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your transformations need to be in your main CSS, not in the `:after` state:

```
.triangle-with-shadow {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 16px 10px -15px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

    transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(180deg); /* IE 9 */
    -moz-transform:rotate(180deg); /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform:rotate(180deg); /* Opera */
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Rotate a triangle 360 degrees from
http://www.identifydesign.net/tutorials/css/triangles-circles/

```
<style type="text/css">

.triangle2{

width:0;
height:0;
border-top:20px solid #000;
border-left:20px solid transparent;
border-right:20px solid transparent;
-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);

}

</style>

<div class="triangle"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just apply the rotate transform to the main element. You'll also want to apply some margin to bring the top edge back into JSFiddle's field of view.

```
.triangle-with-shadow {
   width: 100px;
   height: 50px;
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
   box-shadow: 0 0px 0px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
   transform: rotate(180deg);
   -ms-transform:rotate(180deg); /* IE 9 */
   -moz-transform:rotate(180deg); /* Firefox */
   -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
   -o-transform:rotate(180deg); /* Opera */
   margin-top: 15px;
}
.triangle-with-shadow:after {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   background: #999;
   transform: rotate(45deg);
   -ms-transform:rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
   -moz-transform:rotate(45deg); /* Firefox */
   -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
   -o-transform:rotate(45deg); /* Opera */
   top: 25px;
   left: 25px;
   box-shadow: -1px -1px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}​
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wBUW7/25/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the above answers or you could change the positioning...

```
.triangle-with-shadow {
   width: 100px;
   height: 50px;
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
   box-shadow: 0 -16px 10px -15px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.triangle-with-shadow:after {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   background: #999;
   transform: rotate(45deg);
   -ms-transform:rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
   -moz-transform:rotate(45deg); /* Firefox */
   -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
   -o-transform:rotate(45deg); /* Opera */
   top: -25px;
   left: 25px;
   box-shadow: -1px -1px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}​
```